# How many attacks do Eternal Guard have?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

Warhammer: Wood Elves (2014) lists Eternal Guard on page 92 with one attack in their profile. Under "Equipment" they are listed as being equipped with an Asrai Spear, a Hand Weapon, and Light Armor.

Warhammer (2010) on page 91* notes that models with "Two/Additional Hand Weapons" gain the "Extra Attack" special rule.

**Does the additional Hand Weapon in the equipment profile of the Eternal Guard give them an extra attack?**

Normally a simple reading of the rules would be enough, but I've seen an awful lot of discussion amongst experienced Warhammer players (e.g. http://www.asrai.org/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=26477) either disparaging the new Eternal Guard, or doing math-hammer assuming only one attack each. Since I don't play very often I would usually assume that these veterans know better than me. Am I missing something?

Additionally:- **If so, does this apply even if they are equipped with shields?**

You would assume not, but I don't see anything preventing a model with a shield gaining the extra attack from an additional hand weapon. Not on page 43 under "Sheilds", nor on page 69 under "Extra Attack", nor on page 91 under "Two/Additional Hand Weapons". Clearly it isn't supposed to work like that, so presumably I'm also missing something here?

*I'm (unfortunately!) using the big hardback, so the page number might be different if you're looking at the A5 mini-rulebook.

Comment: I just discovered the FAQ at Black Library. It sensibly adds the "Requires Two Hands" rule to the "Two/Additional Hand Weapons" entry on page 91. That answers my second question, but still leaves me confused about the first part.

Comment: (Technically speaking, "Requires Two Hands" appears to only prohibit you "use" a shield - e.g. to obtain the 6+ ward save - while the bonus armor save only requires that you "carry" a shield... there's clearly a distinction between "carrying" an item and "using" it elsewhere in the book... but that's a stupid interpretation, so I'm going to ignore it)

Comment: Check the Wood Elves book for a detailed description of "Asrai Spear". This should tell you if it counts as a Hand Weapon. The "Two/Additional Hand Weapons" rule requires two or more Hand Weapons, so if the spear is a two-handed weapon or something else special it would not qualify. Frequently in WHF models that have the option of adding shields will be equipped with their main weapon and hand weapon so that you have the option to switch to the shields for better saves in melee and still have a hand weapon with which to attack.

Comment: The Asrai Spear does not have the "Requires Two Hands" USR. Are you saying that gaining an extra attack from an "Additional Hand Weapon" requires that you are using a "Hand Weapon" in your main hand also? Would a model with an ordinary spear and a hand weapon not receive an additional attack?

Comment: All weapons in the WHF world should have a base 'type' they start with, such as Hand Weapon or Great Weapon or possibly Spear. If the Asrai Spear is a type of Spear (Wood Elves book should specifically state what type it is, or else there might be the assumption that it is a Spear since that's in the name), then I'd look in the WHF main rulebook to see what the rules are concerning Spears and the Tow/Additional Hand Weapons rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need two hand weapons to claim an extra attack.  Spear + Hand weapon does not grant a bonus attack.

P89, **Two Special Close Combat Weapons**: "A model can't .. wield .. (an) additional hand weapon alongside another type of special weapon.."

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was referring to the "Requires Two Hands" rule on the Halberd that it references. If that's the case, do you have any idea what the Hand Weapon on the Eternal Guard is for? You can't choose to wield it over the spear alongside the shield for the ward save (p.89)...

Comment: I would guess either 1) army book author forgot you're not allowed to choose anymore and carried forward old wording.  or 2) army book author knows that in next edition of core rules you're going to be allowed to choose again or it will matter in some other way.  (One is kind of hoping that they've been overvaluing Stubborn so badly because they've already decided steadfast is going away.... :) )